# Why do I have to click "Reopen" after I checked "This edit resolves the original close reason" during edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, vote-to-reopen

If I check *This edit resolves the original close reason* during edit:

[image]

Then after saving edited question I must click "Reopen" manually myself.

Shouldn't this be automated? Isn't the fact of checking *This edit resolves the original close reason* an expression of my will that the question is nominated to be reopened?

Comment: Those are two different actions. The goal of this (rather new) checkbox is to signal, not to actually perform the reopen vote itself. (Note the wording, "*should be considered* for reopening")

Comment: Isn't clicking "Reopen" signaling "_should be considered for reopening_" as well? Sorry, if this question is dumb, but I am trying to catch the context or the difference. For me **both** are actually _the same_.

Comment: Not dumb at all, but trying to think how to explain better. However, key point is more technical: those are two different actions. One is just editing, one is voting to reopen. Also, not all users can vote to reopen even their own questions, it requires the [view close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege, usually given at 250 reputation.

Comment: I believe that your second comment actually answers my question.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make any sense. The only people who really benefit from this design are mods who want the community to make reopen decisions instead of unilaterally voting.  Or maybe people who've used up all their reopen votes (never seen that happen, however).

Comment: What would make more sense would be to prohibit the OP from voting to reopen their own post. The vast majority of users who click "This edit resolves the close reason" are lying, knowingly or unknowingly.

Comment: @tripleee Depends on your point of view, context and the situation. I had a number of full-scale edits (to actually resolve the off-topic issue) and my question remained closed after I: (a) checked the magic checkbox, (b) vote to reopen, (c) called of mod, (d) wrote a meta question. All for nothing, so I'd say that this is highly depending on the scenario.